# Looping Through JSON Array Elements in PL/SQL With Single Key

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I loop through elements below when the JSON only has single key value in PL/SQL?
I know how to stringify it but I do not know how to loop each of them.
My code below

```
declare
    l_json_in clob;
    l_json_obj json_object_t;
    l_json_arr json_array_t;
    l_json_out clob;
begin
    l_json_in := '{"List": ["abc","xyz","edf","cbz"]}';
    
    l_json_obj := json_object_t.parse(l_json_in);
    l_json_arr := l_json_obj.get_array('List');
    
    l_json_out := l_json_arr.stringify;

    dbms_output.put_line(l_json_out);

end;
```

Expected output:

abc 
xyz 
edf 
cbz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternative approach, using for loop:

```
declare
    l_json_in clob;
    l_json_obj json_object_t;
    l_json_arr json_array_t;
    l_json_out clob;
begin
    l_json_in := '{"List": ["abc","xyz","edf","cbz"]}';
    
    l_json_obj := json_object_t.parse(l_json_in);
    l_json_arr := l_json_obj.get_array('List');
    
    FOR i IN 0 .. l_json_arr.get_size - 1 LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(l_json_arr.get_string(i));
    END LOOP;
end
;
```

nb: this assume all elements are strings

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
with json as(select '{"List": ["abc","xyz","edf","cbz"]}' txt
from dual)
select value val
from json_table((select txt from json), '$.List[*]'
        columns(value PATH '$')
)
;
```

Comment: please "accept" your answer - this let's everyone know you no longer need assistance (need to wait 48 hours for this)